# Remove the XML header from an XML in Java

Tags: java, xml

```
StringWriter  writer = new StringWriter();
XmlSerializer serializer = new KXmlSerializer();
serializer.setOutput(writer);
serializer.startDocument(null, null);
serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
// Creating XML

serializer.endDocument();
String xmlString = writer.toString();
```

In the above environment, whether there are any standard API's available to remove the XML header `<?xml version='1.0' ?>` or do you suggest to go via string manipulation:

```
if (s.startsWith("<?xml ")) {
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("?>") + 2);
}
```

Wanted the output in the `xmlString` without XML header info `<?xml version='1.0' ?>`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you use a JAXP serializer you get access to all the output properties defined in XSLT, for example `omit-xml-declaration="yes"`. You can get this in the form of an "identity transformer", called using `transformerFactory.getTransformer()` with no parameters, on which you then call `setOutputProperty()`. Another example:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
t.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
```

Comment: There is a constant for the property value: `OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION`

Answer (score 86):

Ideally you can make an API call to exclude the XML header if desired. It doesn't appear that `KXmlSerializer` supports this though (skimming through the code [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/XML/kXML/org/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer.java.htm)). If you had a `org.w3c.dom.Document` (or actually any other implementation of `javax.xml.transform.Source`) you could accomplish what you want this way:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
```

Otherwise if you have to use `KXmlSerializer` it looks like you'll have to manipulate the output.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make call to:

```
serializer.startDocument();
```

It adds the XML header, though you need to call:

```
serializer.endDocument();
```

else your XML will be created as a blank String.