# Convert Element to XML string without <?xml version=...> prefix

Tags: java, xml

I have a legacy code with a lot of `org.w3c.dom.Element` generation like that

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
Element exampleElement = doc.createElement("example");
exampleElement.appendChild(...
```

How can I convert `exampleElement` to XML string like that? *(Any additional libraries is allowed)*

```
<example>
  ...
</example>
```

Not that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>
  ...
</example>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616452/remove-the-xml-header-from-an-xml-in-java Might be useful.

Answer (score 5):

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));
return writer.toString();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION

Answer (score 0):

There's some options:

1. Use an XSL Transformer to apply the changes using the directive **omit-xml-declaration**

   Transformer transformer= TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
   transformer.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
   transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(stream));
2. Use a string replace process to replace the first line with a regex or using an **indexOf("?>")**
3. Depending on the implementation of w3c Document in the JDK used is possible to use some options in DOMConfiguration of the document like [canonical-form](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration.html)

   document.getDomConfig().setParameter("canonical-form",true);